# Table borders look white on a gray background

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have looked up to every thread and nothing seems to be helping. The HTML code is really messed up, however, I will post it right here. I have made all borders to none but it still appears to be white and looks awful.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style4 {
        width: 114%;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style1 {
        width: 206px;
        text-align: right;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style2 {
        width: 935px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style6 {
        width: 935px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style7 {
        width: 198px;
        height: 23px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style9 {
        height: 23px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style10 {
        width: 198px;
        height: 196px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style11 {
        width: 935px;
        text-align: left;
        height: 196px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style12 {
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style13 {
        width: 884px;
        text-align: left;
        height: 23px;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style15 {
        width: 198px;
        height: 30px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style16 {
        border-color: inherit;
        border-width: 0;
        width: 935px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        height: 30px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style17 {
        height: 30px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style19 {
        border-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 935px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        height: 23px;
        border: none;
    }

    .auto-style20 {
        border-color: inherit;
        border-width: 0;
        width: 935px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
```

Below is my HTML code which is messed up.

```
<div style="width: 1400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <table class="auto-style4" border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style10"></td>
            <td class="auto-style11">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="218px" Width="935px" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style7"></td>
            <td class="auto-style19">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSlideshow" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style7"></td>
            <td class="auto-style19">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="#336699" Style="" Text="Schedule A Callback"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            <td class="auto-style16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name :"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Style="" Width="198px"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Enter Name" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style17"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style20">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Contact No :"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" Width="198px" Style=""></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtContact" ErrorMessage="Enter Contact No" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Email :"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtMail" runat="server" Style="" Width="198px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMail" ErrorMessage="Enter Email" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style20">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="City :"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="198px" Style=""></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCity" ErrorMessage="Enter City" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="State :"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Style="" Width="208px">
<asp:ListItem Value="Select">Select</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Andhra Pradesh</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem>West Bengal</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output of my code :**

[image]

Comment: Check my answer. it will help you to resolve your problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer so that it may help other developers as well

Comment: @Mash i compiled your code in browser & i can't see any borders. can you post your output?

Comment: Set 'border-spacing:0;' in table

Answer (score 1):

Just make all Border color to grey..

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
border:none !important;
```

Comment: i am very bad in html. so where do you want me to update this? in html or css?

Comment: in css only ... change all "border:none;" to "border:none ! important;"

Comment: have you try this... "border-color:#C0C0C0;" in css.

Answer (score 0):

Add **cellspacing="0"** in your table as mentioned below :

```
<table class="auto-style4" border="0"  cellspacing="0">
```

This will remove default spacing between your table cells

Answer (score 0):

@Mash this is not an border issue.. just set your table background color... Modify your class like this

```
.auto-style4 {
        width: 114%;
        border:none;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

replace the code..

```
.auto-style4 {
    width: 114%;
    border: none;
    border-spacing:0px;

}
```